# RxJava2: Handling nulls when calling Flowable.toList

Tags: rx-java2

I have the following requirement:
Iterate over an array and for each element emit a method that sometimes can return `Optional.empty` and eventually collect all into a final list which each `Optional.empty` would be swapped with `null`.

```
public class ListWithNullsTest
{
  @Test
  public void testListWithNulls() throws Exception
  {
    generateList(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }) //
        .subscribe( //
            results -> {
              System.out.println(results);
            }, //
            Throwable::printStackTrace //
        );
  }

  private Single<List<Integer>> generateList(Integer[] list)
  {
    return Flowable.fromArray(list) //
        .concatMapSingle(item -> {
          return doSomething(item);
        }) //
        .toList() //
        .map(listWithOptionals -> {
          return listWithOptionals.stream().map(item -> {
            return item.orElseGet(() -> null);
          }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        });
  }

  private Single<Optional<Integer>> doSomething(Integer item)
  {
    if (item % 2 == 0)
    {
      return Single.just(Optional.of(item));
    }

    return Single.just(Optional.empty());
  }
}
```

Results

```
Input: [1,2,3,4,5]
Output: [null,2,null,4,null]
```

I'm trying to find a better way so I don't need to go through creating temp `Optional.empty` instances.
Any ideas?

Comment: is this code compiling? shouldn't it be returning a Single in the `else` branch? also, if the params array contains a null value you should be getting a NPE

Comment: @Gustavo, Fixed - it's just a simplified version of the real code.

Comment: I see.. Flowable.fromArray should also throw NPE if params has a null item

Comment: what's the signature of `doSomething(param)`? If it returns a Single and emits null it will throw NPE

Comment: Currently, it emits `param` (which is never null), but it returns `Optional.empty` in case the results of it processing is null, so the final list may look like: `[Object, Optional.empty, Object]` - all I would like to achieve is `[Object, null, Object]` in case `doSomething` return Optional.empty

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to emit null in RxJava2. If you really want to get null, using `Optional` is the only solution..I guess.. If you concern about creating new instance for each calling `Optional.empty()`, it is fine. Static final constant `Optional.EMPTY` is already defined and return same instance every times.

As for your code, `List` instance was created twice. So I suggest underlying.

```java
    private Single<List<Integer>> generateList(Integer[] list)
    {
        return Flowable.fromArray(list) //
            .map(this::doSomething) //
            .collect(ArrayList::new, (arrayList, item) -> arrayList.add(item.orElse(null)));
    }

    private Optional<Integer> doSomething(Integer item)
    {
        if (item % 2 == 0)
        {
            return Optional.of(item);
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this simple approach:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
List<Integer> transformList = list.stream()
      .map(item -> (item % 2 == 0) ? item : null)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(transformList);
```

**UPDATE**

Your solution is correct and give what you want. I don't quite understand where do you want find "the better way". You can format it better and use `orElse` instead of `orElseGet`:

```java
private Single<List<Integer>> generateList(Integer[] list) {
    return Flowable.fromArray(list)
            .concatMapSingle(item -> doSomething(item))
            .toList()
            .map(listWithOptionals -> listWithOptionals.stream()
                    .map(item -> item.orElse(null))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: This example I gave was just to simplify things, in the real code the array I iterate on is full of different class instances.